# Change environment file path in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to change default .env file path to another one (for usage in production).

In base laravel application I can do this through editing bootstrap/app.php file with adding

```
$app->useEnvironmentPath(...);
```

But Lumen Application class implementation does not support this method

I found solution for public folder path editing through

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() { 
    return __DIR__; 
});
```

in public/index.php, but I can't find something like path.env(ironment).

Help me please with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm lazy. Didn't saw at the top of Lument bootstrap/app.php file next line of code

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
```

And there we can set any .env file location what we prefer

Answer (score 3):

We are using symlinks to point to a specific .env file. We have .env.prod, .env.test files and .env symlink points to .env.prod in production environment. We found this kind of solution.

Comment: The problem is that in fact there is only one .env file on server, and it is placed on the top of directories which contains every specific release version. And each version is linked to that .env file (in common Laravel app). But with lumen I can't figure out how to do this

Comment: Hmm. Think I understood your method. Will try it and give a feedback

Comment: Thanks for your help. My answer below

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
$env = null;

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'zenfy.co'){
    $env = '.env.prod';
}

(new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../', $env))->load();
```

P.s can be a switch when dealing with many hosts...